# Capturing the display with cocos2d on OS X (and Kiosk mode problems)?

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone, kiosk

I built an app with cocos2d for the Mac and implemented [Apple's recommended steps for a Kiosk application](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2062/_index.html). My goal is to have a full screen application that disallows exiting the application and captures all keyboard input.

The problem is that, on an extended keyboard, Kiosk mode does not capture the function keys that control iTunes or the F4 Launchpad key. With process switching disabled, the user can still switch processes by pressing F4. (I filed a Radar on this, since it should be disallowed in Kiosk mode.) I tried subclassing NSApplication. I can detect the press of these keys using the following code:

```
- (void)mediaKeyEvent: (int)key state: (BOOL)state repeat: (BOOL)repeat
{
    switch( key )
    {
        case NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY:
            if( state == 0 )
                NSLog(@"Play pressed and released"); //Play pressed and released
            break;

        case NX_KEYTYPE_FAST:
            if( state == 0 )
                NSLog(@"Next pressed and released"); //Next pressed and released
            break;

        case NX_KEYTYPE_REWIND:
            if( state == 0 )
                NSLog(@"Previous pressed and released"); //Previous pressed and released
            break;

        case NX_KEYTYPE_LAUNCH_PANEL:
            if( state == 0 )
                NSLog(@"Launchpad pressed and released"); //Previous pressed and released
            break;
    }
}
```

I tried to intercept them through a custom implementation of `- (void)sendEvent: (NSEvent*)event`, but they are dispatched to the system regardless of what I do there.

It seems that the solution to this is to "capture the display," per the [Apple programming note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/DisplayCapture.html). When you capture the display, ALL keyboard input is intercepted by the application and none is dispatched further to the system. That's all well and good and I've been able to do it in a vanilla application.

In my cocos2d OS X app, however, control of OpenGL and the GLView is handled in several of the core cocos2d files, namely, `CCGLView.m` and `CCDirectorMac.m`. I've spent hours trying to adjust those files to capture the display, but have been unable to make it work.

For reference, this is what I'm doing (in `AppDelegate.m`) to enter Kiosk mode:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    ...

    NSApplicationPresentationOptions options = NSApplicationPresentationHideDock + NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching + NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar;
    NSNumber *presentationOptions = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:options];
    NSArray *keys   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"NSFullScreenModeAllScreens", @"NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions", nil];
    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], presentationOptions, nil];
    NSDictionary *fullScreenOptions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

    [glView_ enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:fullScreenOptions];

    [director runWithScene:[MyLayer scene]];
}
```

How can I capture the display (note: this is not the same as taking a screenshot!) ***in cocos2d*** and prevent the function keys from speaking to anything other than my application?

---

**Additional info:** `-enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:` does capture the display, but only if you do not send in `NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions` as one of the options. The Apple docs specify this in the NSView and Kiosk mode documentation:

> When the options dictionary you pass to
>   `enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:` does contain a value for
>   `NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions`, AppKit does not
>   capture any displays, because doing so would prevent the showing of
>   presentationOptions-controlled UI elements such as the menu bar and
>   Dock.

Nevertheless, the media/iTunes/volume function keys are not intercepted when you capture the display, which is part of the problem I was trying to answer when I wrote this question. I filed a Tech Support question with Apple because it appears not to be possible to disable them.

Comment: I can't offer an answer so I want to put a suggestion in a comment here - try http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/ which allows you to set how you record your screen, where and when.  I hope you find a better solution!

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I mean by capture the display. I'm not trying to take a screenshot. I'm trying to "capture" it, per this definition provided by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/DisplayCapture.html

Answer (score 0):

Switch the <kbd>fn</kbd> and normal key functions:

- System preferences
- Keyboard
- enable `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as normal keys`

You can then access the normal <kbd>F</kbd> features (volume up, volume down) with <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> and capture the normal `F` keys.

Comment: I'm aware of that capability, but I don't expect everybody who uses the software that I'm trying to make to go through those steps. I simply want to capture the screen in a manner integrated with cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at CarbonEvents.h for information on using `PushSymbolicHotKeyMode` / `PopSymbolicHotKeyMode` with `kHIHotKeyModeAllDisabled`.

Comment: Thank you. I recall looking into that several months ago, but it ended up not being what I needed, though I don't remember why. I'll take another look.

Answer (score -2):

3. Enter the command line: launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist